# css styling using the :nth-child and :not

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a list of `div`s that I want to style using the nth-child selector. I also want to be able to exclude a `div` if it has a certain class, i.e:

```
<style>
 .a:not(.b):nth-child(2n) {
    color: hotpink;
 }
</style>

<div class="a"> Test </div>
<div class="a b"> Test </div>
<div class="a"> I should be pink, as i am the 2nd child that doesnt have a "b" class </div>
<div class="a"> Test </div>
<div class="a"> Test </div>
<div class="a"> Test </div>
<div class="a"> Test </div>
<div class="a"> Test </div>
<div class="a"> Test </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BF7GY/

Comment: It might be worth describing exactly what you are trying to achieve with this, as there might be an easier way. It would also be very easy with javascript if that where an option.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, this isn't possible with current CSS pseudo classes. `nth-child` and similar selectors go off their child index, not child index with `.x` class

Comment: what i am actually trying to do is style a Windows 8 ListView, that when the mouse is down on an item, it injects a hidden div, which in turn re-colours the rest of the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best way would be to use jQuery and two filter() calls like:

```
$('.a').filter(function(){
        return !$(this).hasClass('b');
     }).filter(
    function(i){
        return (i+1)%2 == 0; 
    }
).css('color','hotpink');
```

:not and :nth-child are not as flexible as we would like (unfortunately)

Comment: seems the path to go, shame really thou