# Using nth-child to style a div

Tags: html, css

I have got the following layout, I need to style the first and second div which has got the class `threecolx` but I need to style them differently without adding more classes to them.

HTML

```
<div class="threecolx mobile-hidden">
            <div class="contact-box">
              <span class="promo-text">Family run for over</span>
              <span class="promo-date">- 30 Yrs -</span>
           </div>
          </div>
          <div class="sixcolx">
            <!-- Desktop Logo -->
            <div id="hdr-logo">
              <a href="{SELF_URL}" title="{SITE_NAME}"><img src="/img-src/{v2_FOLDER}/theme/logo.png" alt="{SITE_NAME}" class="responsive-img"/></a>
            </div>
            <!-- // END Desktop Logo -->
          </div>
          <div class="threecolx">
            <div class="contact-box">
              <!-- Social Icons -->
                <div class="telephone"><a href="/contact.php" title="Contact Us"><span class="fa fa-phone"></span> {v2_TELEPHONE_NUMBER}</a></div> 
                <div class="email mobile-hidden"><a href="/contact.php" title="Email us"><span class="fa fa-map-marker"></span> Find Us</a></div>
              <!-- // Social Icons -->
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
```

Here are the styles im using which should work fine!

```
@media screen and (max-width:1200px) {
  #header .row {
    .threecolx:nth-child(1) .contact-box {
      float: right;
    }
    .threecolx:nth-child(2) .contact-box {
      float: left;
    }
  }
}
```

Currently only the first div with the class `threecolx` is being styled, am I using nth-child incorrectly?

Comment: You can use odd and even to style a div alternatively .

Comment: Maybe you should use `nth-of-type` instead. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203313/nth-child-doesnt-respond-to-class-selector

Comment: you are using it correctly, there may be some other style which may be affecting this. Please check it some tool like firebug. If it is in some online page please share the url i will check and let you know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [css styling using the :nth-child and :not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13929997/css-styling-using-the-nth-child-and-not)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes, nth-child does not 'filter' on the selector you have it prefixed with.**

For example, when you type `.threecolx:nth-child(2)` that means that your target element should have a class `threecolx` AND should be the second child of its parent (not the second element with class threecolx in a parent element!)

In your example, threecolx:nth-child(3) should match your target, since it's the third child of its parent. (`.sixcolx` is the second child).

Answer (score 1):

You have `<div class="sixcolx">` in between the `.threecolx` divs, so your second `.threecolx` isn't second but third child

[Here is jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wyx1Ls22/)